# Is emboldening questions a good practice?

Tags: discussion

I have always put my questions in bold to help other users reading and distinguish the question from the context and exemples. It helps to remember and to find it when the text is long. I learnt that from other SE sites.

Sometime, when I read others' questions with a large block of text, I edit it to improve its format and to put in bold the question. **Is this a good practice, here, on Arqade, to do so ?**

I ask this because I have been warned today for the first time after editing [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263187/europa-universalis-iv-kinslayer-achievement-question).

> Please do not just bold words like Question. Think long and hard before bolding anything. It's not automatically a good thing. - Frank

There is probably no real answer, just opinions. In this way, I'll stop this practice if most of the people here thinks that edits for this "is not a good thing".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not everything needs to be bold. It's generally assumed everyone is going to read the entire body of the post. Especially if it is a short post, there's no need to add extra formatting.

In the case of the edit in particular, if you're only editing to add bold and doing nothing else with the post, that's a really minor edit and likely to be rejected. It's not a necessary thing in most cases to add bolding or other formatting changes unless it's a really long post and you want to emphasize the actual question or something like that, but those are incredibly rare, especially here on Arqade.

In general, edits should address as many issues with the post as possible. Not everything needs to be bolded. (If you look on other sites, you will see that in general, formatting like bold or italics isn't something that is used all that often, and we tend to continue that trend here.)

So no, I'd say in the general case, it's not good practice - while I appreciate you are trying to draw eyes to the actual question you are asking, if you need to point it out that much, perhaps you need to edit the question to make it more focused on what you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: +1 for not editing others' questions just to add bold. Definitely think this is a good thing to do to your *own* questions, though.